# Adding steps to make it clearer

Tags: task-flow, task-completion

I am creating an on-boarding process for a tool. In every piece of UX theory it says that is about removing complexity and making it easier for the user to do something.

I'm wondering if it would make sense to add additional steps to the process for the sake of making the user understand the tool?

It would add more steps but in the long term it might help him ramp up in a more natural way.

Answer (score 1):

Removing steps removes complexity, it does not simplify the process. If the process you're creating is complicated, making it go from 7 steps to 5 may not fix the issue.

I used to believe the same, that removing steps is the best practice, but it isn't always the case, especially in complex user transactions. There are a few things worth considering:

1. Are all steps cognitively uniform? For example, if each step has the user do one thing except for one step, does that one step break the flow? If so, better to maintain the one-action-per-step so users don't have to think more about any one step than the others.
2. Is the point of the process lost if not enough steps are taken? This is a unique question I've run into with a recent app, where a microphone peripheral was required and the tutorial had only what was necessary in it (MVP). The first customers to use the app couldn't get the peripheral to work: they said no to the request for the microphone.

The irony is the tutorial was meant to teach the client how to use the app without any training, but within seconds they had failed to do so and said it was broken. Because we missed a step intentionally, half because it was an MVP, half because "everyone should know to say yes when plugging in a microphone-based peripheral". Apparently not. Furthermore, should someone make a mistake, then there needs to be additional steps to explain how to fix the problem! Which leads to...

3. Does it account for user error? Because users make a lot of error and one of the reasons to reduce the number of steps is to reduce user error. That doesn't always work, and in fact may increase user error.

Designers have to take care that for each step removed for the sake of simplicity doesn't cause other challenges like increased user error or dissonance between steps, or else by simplifying they actually complicate.